# In android databinding, how to reference view's own property in its attribute in XML?

Tags: android, android-databinding

```
<ToggleButton
    android:id="@+id/btn_radar"
    android:layout_width="48dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:background="@drawable/btn_radar_selector"
    android:checked="false"
    android:gravity="end"
    android:text=""
    android:textOff=""
    android:textOn=""
    android:visibility="@{bean.shouldHideControls ? View.GONE: (btnRadar.checked? View.INVISIBLE: View.VISIBLE)}"
    tools:visibility="gone"/>
```

I would like to refer to the view's own checked property in `android:visibility` in android databinding, but it fails to compile and outputs the following error:

> Error:(135, 39) Could not resolve the two-way binding attribute 'checked' on type 'android.widget.ImageButton' 
>   Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDevDebugJavaWithJavac'.
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Found data binding errors.

FYI, meanwhile I need to use the passed view model's value which has the same value of its checked value.

Comment: The error message is not from that button but from another as it seems

Comment: @Mono, it is from that because when I double click on the error message, it redirects me to that line of code of `android:visibility`.

Comment: If you just use : android:visibility="@{btnRadar.checked? View.INVISIBLE: View.VISIBLE)} does it work? also what is tools:visibility="gone" <-

Comment: Does NOT work if `android:visibility="@{btnRadar.checked? View.INVISIBLE: View.VISIBLE)}`.

Comment: I think that btnRadar.checked needs to be a bound expression or a bound field and this way. So you need to set android:checked="@{bean.IsChecked} or smth. Then you can do it as far as I understood it.